# Not possible to load skmisc.loess in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, loess

I am using the package plotnine to make ggplot's. In this context I wanted to use "loess". The package gives an error and says: **"For loess smoothing, install 'scikit-misc'"**. I installed it but I still receive this error. It seems that the following statement does not work:

**from skmisc.loess import loess**

It says then **"DLL load failed while importing _loess: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden."** So that the module is not found. From other answers it was suggested that I should install numpy and mkl. I did both, still without any success.

Could you please help me what I can do to use "loess" method?

Thank v much!

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

in colab do this: !pip install scikit-misc (do not need ! in terminal. This works for me)